# How can I apply a color correction LUT to an arbitrary X window on Linux?

Tags: linux, xorg, color-profiles

Here is an explanation of what I mean by LUT:

http://www.lightillusion.com/luts.html

I'd be interested in ways to apply any of the three varieties of LUT described there: a LUT defined by a simple matrix, a generic 1D LUT or generic 3D LUT.

I would like the LUT to be applied to an arbitrary window I specify, without major system performance impact.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux Xorg displays run some ICC style color management tools like KolorServer and CompICC. But as far as I know has Linux no way to run device link style conversions like the above mentioned LUT directly on a display.

One could use a XCM compatible colour server together with the xcm tool. But to reach your goal, someone would need to massage the conversion into a ICC profile before, which might need deeper knowledge with profiling tools like ArgyllCMS or dispcalGUI.